# jquery: How can I add an item before the siblings?

Tags: jquery, insert, siblings

How can I add an item before the siblings?

For instance,

```
<div class="item">1</div>
<div class="item">2</div>
<div class="item">3</div>
```

So I want to add this item before of them.

```
<div class="item">0</div>
```

This one does not work of course!

```
$('<div class="item">0</div>').insertBefore(".item").siblings();
```

This is what I need in the result,

```
<div class="item">0</div>
<div class="item">1</div>
<div class="item">2</div>
<div class="item">3</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the first `.item` and insert your new element before it:

```
$(".item:first").before("<div class='item'>0</div>");
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/Fr3Np/).

Alternatively (for better performance), use `filter`:

```
$(".item").filter(":first").before("<div class='item'>0</div>");
```

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

`$('<div class="item">0</div>').insertBefore(".item:first");`

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
$('.item:eq(1)').parent().prepend('<div class="item">0</div>')
```

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
$("div.class:first").before("<div class='item'>0</div>");
```